# Excel Count unique distinct values that meet multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

have a large spreadsheet with many data columns and dates . Column A have dates and column B have weight in number. I want to calculate how many unique day we have above 30kg [image: example in picture].

Calculated answer must be 2 as we have only 2 days which have above 30 value.

Comment: Can you include your `Formula`?

Comment: I want a formula. I don't know how i will will do that

Comment: I suggest starting by looking at the [`Countifs` formula](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function) and [`Countif` to count uniques](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your date in `A1:B8`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B8>30,A2:A8),A2:A8)>0))
```

Enter as `CSE` through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>